# Can't build project, problems with gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I'm trying to switch from eclipse to android studio for my android development.
However, I still haven't found the right way to import my existing project.
I don't know if it is important: but I'm using a mac

I did the export step in eclipse, imported this gradle build in Android Studio, but when I try to build my project, it gives me this error:

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.
* What went wrong:
Task 'assembleDebug' not found in project ':ProjectName'.
* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.

Could not execute build using Gradle installation '/Users/<username>/Development/Build/gradle-1.6'.
```

This is the build.gradle file that eclipse gave me:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile project(':ProjectName:library:ActionBarSherlock')
    compile project(':ProjectName:library:facebook')
    compile files('../../../../../../../ProjectName/libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('../../../../../../../ProjectName/libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
    compile files('../../../../../../../ProjectName/libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar')
    compile files('../../../../../../../ProjectName/libs/actionbarsherlock-plugin-maps-4.2.0.jar')
    compile files('../../../../../../../NiteOwl/libs/volley.jar')
    compile project(':ProjectName:library:PullToRefresh')
    compile project(':ProjectName:library:google-play-services_lib')
}

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

I've seen a lot of possible solutions, but none of them worked for me, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

The path to the project has no spaces in it

jar libraries => ProjectName/libs

android libraries => ProjectName/library

all of this was working in eclipse

Comment: `/Users/<username>/Development/` .. you replaced your real username with this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We recently moved our project to gradle as well. We ran into issues due to the library projects.

To solve it we added a settings.gradle file in the root of your project with

> include ':libs:actionbarsherlock' 
>   include ':yourprojectname'

Add all your library projects from eclipse into the settings.gradle

We also made a build.gradle file for each of the library Projects.

AFAIK the export from eclipse doesn't deal well with library projects.

Comment: yep, that was the issue, I just wanted to close this issue and answer my own question with the same conclusion. The error message may suggest that there's something wrong with the gradle setup itself, but now that I'm more familiar with the build system I noticed that this kind of error almost always has something to do with a mistake in the build files.

Answer (score 1):

In the build.gradle at the root of your project (the one that's probably mostly empty), add the following line:

```
task assemble{}
```

Found at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57531

Comment: I don't think that this line is necessary, when Gradle wants to use the assemble function, it means that Gradle thinks this project is a pure java project (but it's Android). The android-gradle plugin uses assembleDebug, assembleRelease, ... At some point my setup also required me to do this, but once my build files were ok, this line wasn't necessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this error appear when I had a stray empty flavors stanza in my build.gradle:

```
productFlavors {
}
```